# Autowire placeholder property in prototype bean

Tags: java, spring, autowired

In my application I have a property defined as below:

```
<bean id="DD6Config"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:${file_path}/DD6Config.properties
                </value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I have a prototype bean (DMO_TranslationLabel) where I am autowiring this property (DD6Config).

```
@ANT_MapiTable(name = "TRANSLATION_LABEL")
@Component
@Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class DMO_TranslationLabel
{

    @Autowired
    private Properties DD6Config;
     /*
        business logic here
     */

     if(DD6Config.containsKey("enable_translation")) 
       {
          // Business logic is property is found
       }
}
```

But I am not able to get the bean. DD6Config bean is `null` when accessed at if block.

However, I can get the bean from the application context.

```
ApplicationContext  context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
DD6Config = (Properties) context.getBeanStatic("DD6Config");
```

Why can't I autowire the property in prototype bean? I am able to autowire the same when I change DMO_TranslationLabel to a singleton bean.

Comment: Try adding a `@Qualifier` to your property. Also, note, that you have to always use spring `BeanFactory` for getting prototype bean instances.

Comment: I saw a couple of examples when I googled about adding this line `<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="DD6Config" />`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and it's working fine for both scopes.

Are you using custom ApplicationContext? For instance `getBeanStatic` is not a method of [ApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html).

Comment: Yes I am using a custom getBeanStatic method.